# Recursion better understanding

Tags: javascript

https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/use-recursion-to-create-a-countdown

We have defined a function called countdown with one parameter (n). The function should use recursion to return an array containing the integers n through 1 based on the n parameter. If the function is called with a number less than 1, the function should return an empty array. For example, calling this function with n = 5 should return the array [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]. Your function must use recursion by calling itself and must not use loops of any kind.

```
    // Only change code below this line
   

     function countdown(n){
          if (n<1)
          return [];
          else{
            const numbArray = countdown(n-1);
            numbArray.push(n)
            return numbArray;
          }
        }
        console.log(countdown(5))
    // Only change code above this line
```

comes out like `[1 2 3 4 5]` instead of `[5 4 3 2 1]`

I've been breaking my mind forever then I have completed it with the unshift method but felt like it wanted to me use push even though that sends data to the end of the stack

Comment: If you use [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) instead of `push` you will get `[5,4,3,2,1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function countdown(max, currentN) {
  if (currentN > max)
    return [];
  else if (currentN <= max) {
    const numbArray = countdown(max, currentN + 1);
    numbArray.push(currentN)
    return numbArray;
  }
}
console.log(countdown(5, 1))
// Only change code above this line
```

basically it just counts up to the end value given at start

Comment: Please indent the code properly. Use a Stack Snippet and click the Tidy button.

Answer (score -1):

```
else {
 const arr = []
 arr.push(n)
 return arr.concat(countdown(n-1))
}
```

you can use this code replace, y question reason is y not understand recursion, try to break the point and watch the function execution step by step in the browser or vscode